# Twitter API: How to exclude retweets when searching tweets using Twython

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I'm trying to exclude `retweets` and `replies` in my `Twython` search.

Here is my code:

```
from twython import Twython, TwythonError

app_key = "xxxx"
app_secret = "xxxx"
oauth_token = "xxxx"
oauth_token_secret = "xxxx"   

naughty_words = [" -RT"]
good_words = ["search phrase", "another search phrase"]
filter = " OR ".join(good_words)
blacklist = " -".join(naughty_words)
keywords = filter + blacklist

twitter = Twython(app_key, app_secret, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret) 
search_results = twitter.search(q=keywords, count=100)
```

The problem is that the `-RT` function isn't really working.

**EDIT:**

I've tried @forge suggestion, and while it does print the if tweets are not retweets or replies, when I incorporate them into the code below, the bot still finds tweets, retweets, quotes and replies.

```
twitter = Twython(app_key, app_secret, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret) query = 'beer OR wine AND -filter:retweets AND -filter:replies' 
response = twitter.search(q=query, count=100) 
statuses = response['statuses'] 
try: 
for tweet in statuses: 
try: 
twitter.retweet(id = tweet["id_str"]) 
except TwythonError as e: 
print e 
except TwythonError as e: 
print e
```

Any ideas? Is there a `filter:quotes`?

Comment: i have tried including "-filter:retweets" and "-filter:replies" in my bad words field but not getting any luck. is it really this difficult just to have the api return just tweets and not replies quotes or retweets?

Comment: You can also use as the tutorial given by [Craig Addyman] -  http://www.craigaddyman.com/mining-all-tweets-with-python/

Answer (score 11):

The correct syntax is `-filter:retweets`.

If you would like to search on terms `"search phrase"` or `"another search phrase"` and exclude retweets, then the `query` should be:

```
query = "search_phrase OR another_search_phrase -filter:retweets"
```

To exclude replies as well, add `-filter:replies` like this:

```
query = "search_phrase OR another_search_phrase -filter:retweets AND -filter:replies"
```

This should be working, you can verify it by checking the status fields `in_reply_to_status_id` and `retweeted_status`:

- Status is not a reply if `in_reply_to_status_id` is empty
- Status is not a retweet if it doesn't have the field `retweeted_status`

With `Twython`:

```
import twython

twitter = twython.Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET) 

query = 'wine OR beer -filter:retweets AND -filter:replies' 
response = twitter.search(q=query, count=100)
statuses = response['statuses']
for status in statuses:
    print status['in_reply_to_status_id'], status.has_key('retweeted_status')

# Output should be (None, False) to any status
```

Comment: Beautiful! Also, if anyone wants the API doc for various filters: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/rules-and-filtering/overview/standard-operators